# How to put a picture on top of a background image in the center?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

There is a picture that needs to be placed in the center of the background image. Why doesn't the picture become centered on top of another background image?
It turns out at the top left, but not in the center.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center">
 <ImageView
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/background"/>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/splashlogo2" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of Relative layout use Frame Layout. and Second Image view which you want in the center use layout_gravity instead of gravity

Comment: My Idea. Using ConstraintLayout, you can provide a comfortable layout by dragging and dropping. With RelativeLayout it will be difficult to set it up relatively.

Comment: Pls, try to add android:layout_centerInParent="true" to the ImageView with splash_logo id.

Comment: Vishal Mokal, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replacing `android:gravity...` with `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: Yes replaced "android:gravity" on "android:layout_gravity", as you wrote and it worked for me.

Comment: @EvgenySermyagin enjoy coding!